# Writing tList<string> to tFileStream

Tags: delphi, tlist, tfilestream

I use Berlin in Windows 10. I try to save `tList<string>` to a file.

I know how to handle tStringlist, tStreamWriter and tStreamReader but I need to use tFileStream because the other type of data should be added.

In the following code the loop of Button2Click which reads the data raises an eOutOfMemory exception. When I allocate simple string value to _String it works well but if I put tList value to the same _String it seems that wrong data were written on the file. I can't understand the difference between `_String := _List.List[i]` and `_String := 'qwert'`.

How can I write `tList<string>` to tFileSteam?

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  _List: TList<string>;
  _FileStream: TFileStream;
  _String: string;
  i: Integer;
begin
  _List := TList<string>.Create;

  _List.Add('abcde');
  _List.Add('abcde12345');

  _FileStream := TFileStream.Create('test', fmCreate);

  for i := 0 to 1 do
  begin
    _String := _List.List[i]; // _String := 'qwert' works well

    _FileStream.Write(_string, 4);
  end;

  _FileStream.Free;
  _List.Free;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  _FileStream: TFileStream;
  _String: string;
  i: Integer;
begin
  _FileStream := TFileStream.Create('test', fmOpenRead);

  for i := 0 to 1 do
  begin
    _FileStream.Read(_String, 4);

    Memo1.Lines.Add(_String);
  end;

  _FileStream.Free;
end;
```

Comment: Have you tried serializing it?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams No I didn't. I'm sorry that I've never heard of that.

Comment: Why are you not using [TStringList](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TStringList), it has SaveToFile and LoadFromFile methods?

Comment: `TList<string>` is a perfectly reasonably choice. Less cluttered that `TStringList` with its `Objects[]` property, if you don't use that.

Comment: @whosrdaddy I'm sorry that I mistyped tStringlist as tStringgrid. I've corrected it. I know how to use tStringlist but I need to add integer, extended or something to the same tFilestream. Thanks.

Comment: If you just puke it all into the file how will you know what types the data are when reading. Think about it a little. Asking how to code this is pointless. You don't even know what you want to do yet. Coding will be the easy part. One option is to write json output. But it is up to you.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I know what types of data and what sizes of them are there because I write them and I read them with the order and each size of it according to the written sequence. By the way Is it the problem of serializing? I can't find any useful content from references. Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at this example from the Delphi docs: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Seattle/en/StreamCharRdWr_(Delphi). It is about `TStreamWriter` and `TStreamReader`. These can write and read quite a number of types, including strings. That is serializing.

Comment: I very much doubt that much good will come of your current approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you lookup in the docs what `TFileStream.Write` does, it tells you (inherited from `THandleStream.Write`):

> ```
> function Write(const Buffer; Count: Longint): Longint; override;
> function Write(const Buffer: TBytes; Offset, Count: Longint): Longint; override;
> ```
>
> Writes Count bytes from the Buffer to the current position in the
>   resource.

Now, `Buffer` is untyped and as such is expected to be the memory address of the data to be written. You are passing a string variable which is a reference to the actual string data, the address of the variable holds a pointer to string data. You are therefore writing a pointer to the file.

To correct it pass the strings first character for the buffer, `....write(_string[1], ...`
If you have compiler directive {$ZEROBASEDSTRINGS ON} you would use index 0.
Alternatively, typecast the string to `PChar` and dereference it: `....write(PChar(_String)^, ...`

Then look at the second parameter, `Count`. As the docs say, it indicates the number of **bytes** to be written, specifically not characters. In Delphi 2009 and later strings are `UnicodeString`, so each character is 2 bytes. You need to pass the strings size in bytes.

This will write 4 characters (8 bytes) to the file stream:

```
_FileStream.Write(_String[1], 4 * SizeOf(Char));
```

or better

```
_FileStream.Write(PChar(_String)^, 4 * SizeOf(Char));
```

For reading you need to make corresponding changes, but most notable, you need to set the strings length before reading (length is counted in characters).

```
  SetLength(_String, 4);
  for i := 0 to 1 do
  begin
    _FileStream.Read(_String[1], 4 * SizeOf(Char));

    Memo1.Lines.Add(_String);
  end;
```

---

To continue with this low-level approach you could generalize string writing and reading as follows:
Add a variable to hold the length of a string

```
var
  _String: string;
  _Length: integer;
```

then writing

```
begin
  ...
  for ....
  begin
    _String := _List.List[i];
    _Length := Length(_String);
    _FileStream.Write(_Length, SizeOf(Integer));
    _FileStream.Write(PChar(_List.List[i])^, _Length * SizeOf(Char));
  end;
```

and reading

```
begin
  ...
  for ....
  begin
    _FileStream.Read(_Length, SizeOf(Integer));
    SetLength(_String, _Length);
    _FileStream.Read(_String[1], _Length * SizeOf(Char));
    Memo1.Lines.Add(_String);
  end;
```

IOW, you write the length first and then the string. On reading you read the length and then the string.

Comment: Writing _List.Add('abcde'); _String := _List.List[0]; _FileStream.Write(_string[1], 5); and reading   SetLength(_String, 5);   _FileStream.Read(_String[1], 5); works well. Your comment was so helpful that I can solve the problem. Writing and reading should have the size of each tList item and this is annoying. It's better to use ShortString of static string. Thanks a lot.

Comment: In the case of string[1] the length should be length * 2. Your comment about unicode was very helpful. Thanks a lot.